# Why does this simple way to replace an entry in a data fram in R not work?

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

Surely I am missing something here.  I am reading [this documentation](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/r-project/arch/i386_rhel3/lib/R/library/base/html/Extract.data.frame.html):

Now, if I have any old vector:

```
x <- letters
```

I can do this:

```
x[5] <- "test"
```

... and the letter "e" in the vector x will be replaced by the string "test".  So far so good, but if I make a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = letters, col2 = letters)
```

then why do I get errors for:

```
 df[5,1] <- "test"
```

and

```
 df$col1[5] <- "test"
```

?

There MUST be an extremely simple way to do this, to get in to a data frame and change just one single value.

The error is "invalid factor level."   So I suppose that ideally the way would be to somehow tell R that I want it to NOT treat the relevant column in the DF as a factor variable.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `stringsAsFactors` argument to `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = letters, col2 = letters, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

This will give columns of mode `character`, as you want.

`?data.frame` shows its options.